# Use jQuery to set focus on a prefilled form field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select, focus

When a page including a form is loaded and the first input-text field has a value the focus automatically jumps to the second field.

How can i set the focus on the first field and have the prefilled-text/value seleted? - I don't want the cursor to sit at the end of the prefilled-text/value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution ist to use

```
$(yourElement).select();
```

the problem was, that some homebrewed dialog framework turned the *$(document).ready(function(){...})* i was using, into foobar.

By moving my .select() to the dialog framework function handling the afterLoad i was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use autofocus:

```
<form name="test">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Alexandre" autofocus />

    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" />
</form>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CpP6k/)

Comment: what browser are you using? unfortunately i can't see neither your fiddle, nor my form working in firefox (24.3).

Comment: I use chrome 33, but I've test in firefox 27.0.1 and it also works.